# httppostedfilebase receive null in Web API when requested from Postman

Tags: asp.net-web-api, postman, httppostedfilebase

I was trying to send a post request to my API controller. It receives all input except file input. I tried few solutions but nothing is working. I created same form in MVC and it worked but doesn't work in API where am I lacking.

My Blogger Controller / Create action

```
public HttpResponseMessage Create(Blogger objBlogger)
{

}
```

My Blogger Model

```
public class Blogger
{
    public string Blogger_Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string BloggerName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string BloggerUserName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"^([\w\.\-]+)@([\w\-]+)((\.(\w){2,3})+)$")]
    public string BloggerEmail { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression("^[0-9]*$")]
    public string BloggerMobileNumber { get; set; }
    public string BloggerProfilePicture { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string BloggerPassword { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase UploadProfilePicture { get; set; }
}
```

My Postman Code

```
POST /api/Blogger/Create HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3694
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 8097929a-bc93-42a4-8bc8-0e9ea98a279e

------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="BloggerName"

DemoName
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="BloggerUserName"

DemoUserName
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="BloggerEmail"

DemoEmail@gmail.com
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="BloggerMobileNumber"

9999999999
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="UploadProfilePicture"; filename="asset.JPG"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="BloggerPassword"

DemoPassword
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
```

Answer (score 1):

For Web API use something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Create()
{
    if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
    {
        this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
    }

    string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/temp");
    var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);
    var result = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

    // Files
    foreach (MultipartFileData file in provider.FileData)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName);
        Debug.WriteLine("File path: " + file.LocalFileName);
    }

    // Form data
    foreach (var key in provider.FormData.AllKeys)
    {
        foreach (var val in provider.FormData.GetValues(key))
        {
            // your Blogger obj
            ...
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I want it in objBlogger httppostedfilebase variable as we receive in MVC

Comment: I'm not aware of out-of-the-box way, but you could achieve something like that by using ModelBinder (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api). That way you'd implement everything I've wrote in your model binder and then in your controller have everything ready in method param.

Comment: Why can file not be bind like rest of the form-data?

Comment: Can you try implementing something like this: https://gist.github.com/Danielku15/bfc568a19b9e58fd9e80